# Bootstrap Carousel not working in web browsers but working in mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, carousel

I have corrected in many ways my bootstrap carousel working on mobile not in web browsers. Even i cleared my browser's cache. **No sliding effect while clicking on indicator** and even everything is in perfect order. other pc it is working.
Have a  look at my site please [here](https://mysite2022demo.xyz/solutions/services/webdesign.php)

and here is my cod

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myCarousel').carousel({
    interval: 5000
  });
});
```

```css
.ff {
  max-width: 4% !important;
}
```

```html
<!-- bootstrap css-->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Fancybox app -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fancyapps/ui@4.0/dist/fancybox.css" />

<!-- Font awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<!-- Gallery BRAND WEB DESIGN PORTFOLIO -->
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 pb-5 padding text-center portfoliotitle">
        <h5>WEBSITE SHOWCASE</h5>
        <h1>This website development company <br> has actualized numerous website ideas into reality. <br> Indulge yourself into our website development and <br> design projects.</h1>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
</section>


<div class="container text-center my-3">
  <div class="row mx-auto my-auto">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide w-100" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item py-5 active">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/5b.png" data-fancybox="gallery">
                                        <img src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/5.png" />
                                    </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/5b.png" data-fancybox="gallery">
                                        <img src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/5.png" />
                                    </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/5b.png" data-fancybox="gallery">
                                        <img src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/5.png" />
                                    </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/5b.png" data-fancybox="gallery">
                                        <img src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/5.png" />
                                    </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/5b.png" data-fancybox="gallery">
                                        <img src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/5.png" />
                                    </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/5b.png" data-fancybox="gallery">
                                        <img src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/5.png" />
                                    </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/5b.png" data-fancybox="gallery">
                                        <img src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/5.png" />
                                    </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/5b.png" data-fancybox="gallery">
                                        <img src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/5.png" />
                                    </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/5b.png" data-fancybox="gallery">
                                        <img src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/5.png" />
                                    </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/5b.png" data-fancybox="gallery">
                                        <img src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/5.png" />
                                    </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item py-5">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/5b.png" data-fancybox="gallery">
                                        <img src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/5.png" />
                                    </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/5b.png" data-fancybox="gallery">
                                        <img src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/5.png" />
                                    </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/5b.png" data-fancybox="gallery">
                                        <img src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/5.png" />
                                    </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/5b.png" data-fancybox="gallery">
                                        <img src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/5.png" />
                                    </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/5b.png" data-fancybox="gallery">
                                        <img src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/5.png" />
                                    </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/5b.png" data-fancybox="gallery">
                                        <img src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/5.png" />
                                    </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/5b.png" data-fancybox="gallery">
                                        <img src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/5.png" />
                                    </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/5b.png" data-fancybox="gallery">
                                        <img src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/5.png" />
                                    </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
    <div class="col col-lg-2 ff">
      <a class="carousel-control-prev text-dark" href="#myCarousel" role="dot" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next text-dark" href="#myCarousel" role="dot" data-slide="next">
        <span class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-VHvPCCyXqtD5DqJeNxl2dtTyhF78xXNXdkwX1CZeRusQfRKp+tA7hAShOK/B/fQ2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fancyapps/ui@4.0/dist/fancybox.umd.js"></script>
```

Comment: That site doesn't use a bootstrap carousel, it uses Owl. Is that the right site?

Comment: @Ouroborus i uses both. owl carousel and bootstrap carousel. check here: https://mysite2022demo.xyz/solutions/services/webdesign.php

Comment: Seems to be working on Android. Though the slide content needs to be adjusted for mobile.

Comment: @Ouroborus i want to make it work on browsers???????

Comment: It's working in chrome. What browser are you using?

Comment: Oh, usually it's mobile that's the problem. However, it works fine in Firefox.

Comment: @ruleboy21google chrome even i installed firefox... not working for me. only working in mobile. i want to make it work for me in browsers too.

Comment: @Ouroborus thank you..

Answer (score 0):

I found solutions afte 1 day. If you close animation from windows, it will close all animation from all browsers. From **Settings > Ease of Access > Show animations in Windows > ON**. Here is the help I took from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63828374/carousel-sliding-animation-not-working-on-bootstrap-4-5-2).